# Extract just the OpenAI "content" that is generated using OpenAI API

Tags: php, wordpress, openai-api

So I have this portion of the code:

```
        $prompt = "Act as a marketing manager and use the <promotion> to create an authentic and unique instagram caption. Ensure that there are no emojis and we keep it to 6 lines maximum. Act as if a millennial wrote it and make sure it sound in third-person. Don't use any quotation marks when outputting the answer.

        Promotion = $content";

        $data = [
        'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        'messages' => [
            [
              'role' => 'user',
              'content' => $prompt
            ]
        ] 
    ];
    $api_key = 'test';
    $response = wp_remote_post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", [
            'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,  
        ],
            'body' => wp_json_encode($data)
    ]);
    if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
        $result = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
        $chatgpt_content = $result->choices[0]->message->content;
        var_dump($chatgpt_content);
    }
```

When I output the var_dump, I get the following:

```
array(2) { ["model"]=> string(13) "gpt-3.5-turbo" ["messages"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["role"]=> string(4) "user" ["content"]=> string(629) "Act as a marketing manager and use the to create an authentic and unique instagram caption. Ensure that there are no emojis and we keep it to 6 lines maximum. Act as if a millennial wrote it and make sure it sound in third-person. Don't use any quotation marks when outputting the answer. Promotion = Experience St. Louis’ favorite evening under the stars! Bring a picnic blanket to Art Hill and enjoy offerings from local food trucks, a stunning fireworks show, and free live music—from beloved movie themes to exciting classical tunes—by your SLSO.

https://www.facebook.com/events/661497125485495/" } } } string(505) "Experience the ultimate evening under the stars in St. Louis! Grab a picnic blanket and head to Art Hill for a night filled with local food truck delights, a breathtaking fireworks display, and live music that will transport you to the magical world of beloved movies and exhilarating classical melodies. Join your SLSO and make unforgettable memories at this must-attend event. Don't miss out! #StLouisUnderTheStars #FoodTruckFiesta #FireworksSpectacular #LiveMusicMagic #SLSOSounds #UnforgettableEvening"
```

The problem is that the "content" output includes both my input and also the ChatGPT output, does anyone know how to return just the ChatGPT output? The portion where it begins with "Experience" is the ChatGPT output.

Does anyone know what I could do?

Not getting the proper output.